# How to use Scrapy's MapCompose input processor

Tags: python, scrapy

In the Scrapy shell for the website http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/sheets/sheets-1-7-152-06-release/google-sheets-1-7-152-06-30-android-apk-download/, I'm trying to parse the `version_name` (`1.7.152.06.30`) and `version_code` (`7152063`) (see screenshot below) in a succinct way using Scrapy's [MapCompose](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.MapCompose) processor.

[image]

My first step is to get all the text from the 'APK details' section:

```
In [2]: apk_details = response.xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]//text()').extract()
```

upon which `apk_details` is a list as follows:

```
[u'Version: 1.7.152.06.30 (71520630)',
 u'arm ',
 u'Package: com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets',
 u'\n',
 u'191 downloads ']
```

I've defined the following auxiliary functions:

```
import re

def get_version_line(apk_details):
    '''Get the line containing the version from the 'APK details' section.'''
    return next(line for line in apk_details if line.startswith("Version:"))

def parse_version_line(version_line):
    '''Parse the 'versionName' and 'versionCode' from the relevant line in 'APK details'.'''
    PATTERN = r"^Version: (?P<version_name>.+) \((?P<version_code>\d+)\)\s*$"       # Note that the pattern includes the end-of-line character ($). This is necessary because some package names (e.g. Google Play) themselves contain brackets.
    return re.match(PATTERN, version_line).groupdict()
```

such that the `version_name` can be obtained as follows:

```
In [4]: version_line = get_version_line(apk_details)

In [5]: version_line
Out[5]: u'Version: 1.7.152.06.30 (71520630)'

In [6]: groups = parse_version_line(version_line)

In [7]: groups
Out[7]: {'version_code': u'71520630', 'version_name': u'1.7.152.06.30'}

In [8]: version_name = groups.get("version_name")

In [9]: version_name
Out[9]: u'1.7.152.06.30'
```

In other words, I'd like to apply `get_version_line`, `parse_version_line`, and `lambda d: d.get("version_name")` successively to `apk_details`. However, if I try the following:

```
In [10]: proc = MapCompose(get_version_line, parse_version_line)

In [11]: proc(apk_details)
```

I get a `StopIteration` exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-59a0bd60721d> in <module>()
----> 1 proc(apk_details)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/loader/processors.pyc in __call__(self, value, loader_context)
     26             next_values = []
     27             for v in values:
---> 28                 next_values += arg_to_iter(func(v))
     29             values = next_values
     30         return values

/home/kurt/dev/apkmirror_scraper/apkmirror_scraper/items.pyc in get_version_line(apk_details)
     33 def get_version_line(apk_details):
     34     '''Get the line containing the version from the 'APK details' section.'''
---> 35     return next(line for line in apk_details if line.startswith("Version:"))
     36 
     37 def get_architectures_line(apk_details):

StopIteration:
```

How would I correctly use `MapCompose` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Compose instead with re.MULTILINE flag:

```
import re
from scrapy.loader.processors import Compose


def parse_version_line(version_line):
    """Parse the 'versionName' and 'versionCode' from the relevant line in 'APK details'."""
    text = '\n'.join(version_line)
    PATTERN = r"^Version: (?P<version_name>.+) \((?P<version_code>\d+)\)\s*$"  # Note that the pattern includes the end-of-line character ($). This is necessary because some package names (e.g. Google Play) themselves contain brackets.
    return re.match(PATTERN, text, re.MULTILINE).groupdict()
```

Trying it out:

```
data = [u'Version: 1.7.152.06.30 (71520630)',
        u'arm ',
        u'Package: com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets',
        u'\n',
        u'191 downloads ']
m = Compose(parse_version_line)
print(m(data))
# {'version_name': u'1.7.152.06.30', 'version_code': u'71520630'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Granitosaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3737009/granitosaurus)' answer, I found that the solution was simply to use Scrapy's [Compose](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.Compose) processor rather than [MapCompose](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.processors.MapCompose):

```
In [26]: proc = Compose(get_version_line, parse_version_line, lambda d: d.get("version_name"))

In [27]: print proc(apk_details)
1.7.152.06.30
```

Having read more closely the documentation, this makes sense: broadly speaking, `Compose` generates the composition of the given functions on the 'entire' input, whereas `MapCompose` performs the compossed function on each element.